# View don't want to be updated

Tags: android

I have a problem to update my view that changes the color in MainActivity. I click on cardview, entering the "Edit note" and change the color - all work, but when I return to see all notes the color doesn't change but when I close the app and launch it - color has changed. I can't figure out what's wrong with this behaviour

MainActivity: onActivityResult

```
    if(requestCode == ADD_NOTE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String title = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteeActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
        String text = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteeActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);
        String selectedColor = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteeActivity.EXTRA_VIEW);

        Notee notee = new Notee(title, text, selectedColor);
        noteeViewModel.insert(notee);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Note saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if(requestCode == EDIT_NOTE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        int id = data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteeActivity.EXTRA_ID, -1);

        if(id == -1){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Note can't be updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        String title = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteeActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
        String text = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteeActivity.EXTRA_TEXT);
        String selectedColor = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteeActivity.EXTRA_VIEW);

        Notee notee = new Notee(title, text, selectedColor);
        
        notee.setId(id);
        noteeViewModel.update(notee);
        
        Toast.makeText(this, "Note updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Note not saved    ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

EditNoteActivity: saveNote

```
    String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
    String text = editText.getText().toString();
    String selectedColor = selectedNoteeColor;


    if(title.trim().isEmpty() || text.trim().isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please make a notes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_VIEW, selectedColor);

    int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
    if (id != -1) {
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);
    }

    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
}
```

NoteeRepository

```
public class NoteeRepository {

private NoteeDao noteeDao;
private LiveData<List<Notee>> allNotes;


public NoteeRepository(Application application){
    NoteeDatabase database = NoteeDatabase.getInstance(application);
    noteeDao = database.noteeDao();
    allNotes = noteeDao.getAllNotes();
}

public void insert(Notee notee){

    new InsertNoteeAsynTask(noteeDao).execute(notee);

}

public void delete(Notee notee){
    new DeleteNoteeAsynTask(noteeDao).execute(notee);
}

public void update(Notee notee){
    new UpdateNoteeAsynTask(noteeDao).execute(notee);
}

public void deleteAllNotees(){
    new DeleteAllNoteesAsynTask(noteeDao).execute();
}

public LiveData<List<Notee>> getAllNotes(){
    return allNotes;
}

private static class InsertNoteeAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Notee, Void, Void>{

    private NoteeDao noteeDao;

    private InsertNoteeAsynTask(NoteeDao noteeDao){
        this.noteeDao = noteeDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Notee...notees){

        noteeDao.insert(notees[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class DeleteNoteeAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Notee, Void, Void>{

    private NoteeDao noteeDao;

    private DeleteNoteeAsynTask(NoteeDao noteeDao){
        this.noteeDao = noteeDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Notee...notees){
        noteeDao.delete(notees[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class UpdateNoteeAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Notee, Void, Void>{

    private NoteeDao noteeDao;

    private UpdateNoteeAsynTask(NoteeDao noteeDao){
        this.noteeDao = noteeDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Notee...notees){
        noteeDao.insert(notees[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

private static class DeleteAllNoteesAsynTask extends AsyncTask<Notee, Void, Void>{

    private NoteeDao noteeDao;

    private DeleteAllNoteesAsynTask(NoteeDao noteeDao){
        this.noteeDao = noteeDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Notee...notees){
        noteeDao.deleteAllNote();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

@Entity (tableName = "note_table")
public class Notee {

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;

private String title;
private String text;
private String image;


public Notee(String title, String text, String image) {
    this.title = title;
    this.text = text;
    this.image = image;

}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}
```

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteeHolder holder, int position) {

```
    Notee currentNotee = getItem(position);
    holder.textViewText.setText(currentNotee.getText());
    holder.textViewTitle.setText(currentNotee.getTitle());
    holder.viewColor.setBackground(new ColorCircleDrawable(Color.parseColor(currentNotee.getImage())));
}


// Get the position of the notees

public Notee getNoteAt(int position){
    return getItem(position);
}




class NoteeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textViewTitle;
    private TextView textViewText;
    private View viewColor;

    public NoteeHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textViewText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        viewColor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.color);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if(listener != null && position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    listener.OnItemClick(getItem(position));
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

from NoteeViewModel

```
  public class NoteeViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private NoteeRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Notee>> allNotes;

    public NoteeViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new NoteeRepository(application);
        allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
    }

    public void insert(Notee notee){
        repository.insert(notee);
    }

    public void delete(Notee notee){
        repository.delete(notee);
    }

    public void update(Notee notee){
        repository.update(notee);
    }

    public void deleteAllNote(){
        repository.deleteAllNotees();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Notee>> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }
}
```

from MainActivity onCreate

```
noteeViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteeViewModel.class);
        noteeViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, new Observer<List<Notee>>() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(@NonNull List<Notee> notees){
                adapter.submitList(notees);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is ok for this but the problem is somewhere with the noteeViewModel, probably... Check if you used removeSource somewhere

Is everything okay when you create a new note?
Do you have a problem only with color? If the title and text are refreshed and the color is not then, there is a problem with RecyclerView...

**Instead of onActivityResult it would be better to create an AdEditViewModel for AddEditNoteeActivity (for Edit send note ID with bundle), create or edit loaded note (loaded by id) and save it... when you return to the MainActivity room it will refresh the notes if you are not unsubscribe it

EDITED:

I was very curious about your problem so I tried your code and everything works fine with both insert and update

With your code i used:

gradle file

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation  "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor  "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
```

dao

```
@Dao
public interface NoteeDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM note_table ORDER BY id")
    public LiveData<List<Notee>> readAll();  
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertList(List<Notee> notees);
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(Notee... notees);
    @Update
    void update(Notee... notees);
    @Delete
    void delete(Notee notee);

}
```

databese

```
public static NoteeDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (NoteeDatabase.class) {
                if (sInstance == null) {
                    sInstance = buildDatabase(context.getApplicationContext());
                    sInstance.updateDatabaseCreated(context.getApplicationContext());
                }
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
```

Check these things or you can try to rebuild app, invalidate cash...
Also ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteeViewModel.class) is deprecated but it works... search for more details about that

Comment: It's ok when I create a new note but I noticed that when I update not only the color but the text too the color is updated

Comment: You wrote that when you reload everything the color is an updated... Can you post some code from MainActivity with observe method on notes from noteeViewModel and method from noteeViewModel where you load LiveData<List<Notee>>

Comment: I was referring to the place where you load notes, also the method from the repository if you use it. 
It's weird that the list refreshes when you create a note and doesn't refresh when you update and use the same source (I guess you use). 
Try to use insert instead of update like this in NoteeDao

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(Notee item);

and change to noteeDao.insert(notees[0]); in updateNoteAsyncTask

this is not the solution, just to see what happens!!

Comment: added your code, all work the same and as usual
also updated post with full NoteeRepository and NoteeViewModel
it seems to me that the problem maybe in NoteeRepository due to not correct AsyncTask code, but I don't understand how to write it better